# Updating Users Info

Tags: php, pdo

What i'm trying to do is to `update` the users level but when I try to update the user it always `sets` the `value` to 1 for the some reason. I'm not sure if the HTML part is wrong or the PHP part is incorrect, because it looks like it does update but it's not setting the correct value I ask it to do.

Here my following code (I know there's a better way to do this like calling it in a function but I just wanted to start out simple and lead my way up-top)

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $ulevel    = is_numeric($_POST['level']);
    $nusername    = $_POST['username'];

            $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET level = :Level WHERE username = :Player");
            $sql->bindParam(':Player',$nusername);
            $sql->bindParam(':Level',$ulevel);
           if($sql->execute()){
                $msg =  $msg."Permission have been updated!";
            } else {
                $msg = $msg."Problems changing permissions";
            }

        }


?>
```

and here is the HTML forum.

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>[Enhance '.$username.'\'s Player Permissions]</p>
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$username.'" name="username">
        User Level
        <input type=range min=0 max=5 name="level" value="'.$userLevel.'" id=fader step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
        <output for=fader id=volume>'.$userLevel.'</output><br>
</form>
```

The `$userlevel` and `$username` are variables that gets the data $username is  `$username = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : die();` and level is `$userLevel = $dbUser['level'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the Level using the boolean response from [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), it's only ever going to return 1 or 0 depending on the value for `level`

```
$ulevel = is_numeric($_POST['level']);
```

Try

```
if (isset($_POST['update']) && is_numeric($_POST['level'])) {
   $ulevel = $_POST['level'];

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just figured that was the problem right when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

dude in
     `$ulevel = is_numeric($_POST['level']);`
is_numeric returns 1 or 0 in answer put it in if condition like

```
$ulevel = echo(is_numeric($_POST['level'] && !empty(is_numeric($_POST['level']))?$_POST['level']:"";
```

ok now